# Application freezes on Glide call to submit().get()

Tags: java, android, multithreading, google-maps, android-glide

I am trying to create a custom cluster icon for my Google Map. 
I've previously tried extending AsyncTask, and using execute().get() to retrieve the drawable from submit().get() but the same thing occurs as with implementing Callable. I have also tried to get the ImageView from load(uri).into(imageView) but the operation is completed after the rest of the code.

```
final List<Drawable> profilePhotos = new ArrayList<>(Math.min(4, markerCluster.getSize()));

for (MarkerCluster p : markerCluster.getItems()) {
//                         Draw 4 at most.
    if (profilePhotos.size() == 4) break;
    final Uri bitmapUri = Uri.parse(p.getDescription());
    Drawable drawable = null;GlideBitmapBuilder(bitmapUri));

    try {
        drawable = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor().submit(new GlideBitmapBuilder(bitmapUri)).get();
        } catch (ExecutionException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        drawable.setBounds(0, 0, 200, 200);
        profilePhotos.add(drawable);
}
MultiDrawable multiDrawable = new MultiDrawable(profilePhotos);
multiDrawable.setBounds(0, 0, 200, 200);
clusterImage.setImageDrawable(multiDrawable);
Bitmap icon = clusterIcon.makeIcon(String.valueOf(markerCluster.getSize()));
markerOptions.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(icon));
```

Where the GlideBitmapBuilder class is:

```
private class GlideBitmapBuilder implements Callable<Drawable> {

        Uri bitmapUri;

        private GlideBitmapBuilder(Uri bitmapUri) {
            this.bitmapUri = bitmapUri;
        }

        @Override
        public Drawable call() throws Exception {
          drawable = GlideApp.with(getApplication()).load(bitmapUri).submit(200, 200).get();
            return drawable;
        }
    }
```

The expected result should be a successful return of the drawable variable from where I would be able to create the icons for my clusters, but it ends up freezing at the point where I get the drawable from GlideApp.

I am out of ideas for how I should approach this, so any help would be greatly. Is there a way to have submit().get() not freeze? Or is there a better way to render cluster icons?

Thank you very much

Comment: It's freezing because you're calling `get()`. `get()` waits for the task to complete, thereby completely invalidating the point of an AsyncTask. Look into how you can make a callback.

Comment: @TheWanderer I have tried callbacks before with SimpleTarget and RequestListener, but it ends up not being run before the cluster icon is rendered, so in the end the I only have the default icon